# illegal start of simple expression and dont know why?

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Poster</th>
        <th>Post</th>
        <th>Bearbeiten</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @for((result, index) <- posts.zipWithIndex) {
            @if(@result.getPoster() == @userid){
            <tr>
                <td>@{index + 1}</td>
                <td>@result.getPoster_name()</td>
                <td>@result.getPost()</td>
                <td><a href = "/post/@result.getId()">Bearbeiten</a></td>
            </tr>
            }else{
            <tr>
                <td>@{index + 1}</td>
                <td>@result.getPoster_name()</td>
                <td>@result.getPost()</td>
                <td>nicht dein Post</td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

When I try to compile this I get the error illegal start of simple expression in the line
@{index + 1} in the if-statment. Can someone help me please I have know idea why this isnt working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only use `@` when starting an expression or block. So in this line

```
@if(@result.getPoster() == @userid)
```

use this instead

```
@if(result.getPoster == userid)
```

Answer (score 1):

the template engine automatically detects the end of your code block. if you already marked your code with a @ , you don't need to repeat it until the end of that expression. so this will do the job:

```
@if(result.getPoster == userid)
```

you are getting the error at the `@{index + 1}` line, but the problem is actually in the `@if(@result.getPoster() == @userid)` line.

I also have 2 improvements for you code here, if your `userid` is a Long, DO NOT compare it with `==` sign, it only works with Long objects lower than 127.

and instead of writing `href = "/post/@result.getId()"` you can use your routes. (a dynamic link)